# Python: GUI widget to export code for user created graphs charts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

My knowledge of python is limited. I have been using matplotlib for sometime know to plot simple charts. I can create a lot of features, but I am not able to fine tune the quality and look of the graph to the extent I want. Is there a GUI widget that allows us to manually create charts like in excel, but once the charts are created, the underlying python code can be exported? It is probably asking for too much, but that would make my life easy.

Here is an example of what I mean. The following is the code I used to create the chart below. The legend is not solid white, like I want it to be. Additionally, I tried to display the value of the last data point in the time series. After much trials, I could not get it to display. It is just frustrating to work with matplotlib. If I change the sequence of some of the lines of the code, I get completely different result.

```
data['BUFFETT RATIO']=data['WILL5000'].div(data['GDP'])
fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9))
ax1 = ax0.twinx()
data['Y0'] = 0.0
data['Y1'] = 0.5
data['Y2'] = 0.75
data['Y3'] = 0.90
data['Y4'] = 1.15
data['Y5'] = 1.75
data['BUFFETT RATIO'].plot(kind='line', stacked=False, ax=ax0, color='black',LW=3, label="Buffett Ratio")
ax0.yaxis.grid(True)
#ax0.grid(True)
ax0.set_ylim(0,1.75)
vals = ax0.get_yticks()
ax0.set_yticklabels(['{:3.0f}%'.format(x*100) for x in vals])
plt.title('Buffett Ratio - Total Market Capitalization (Wilshire 5000 Full Cap. Price Index) to Gross Domestic Product')
ax0.fill_between(data.index,data.Y0, data.Y1, alpha=.3, facecolor='g',label="        <- 50%   --  Significantly Undervalued")
ax0.fill_between(data.index,data.Y1, data.Y2, alpha=.3, facecolor='c',label="50% <- 75%   --  Modestly Undervalued")
ax0.fill_between(data.index,data.Y2, data.Y3, alpha=.3, facecolor='peachpuff',label="75% <- 90%   --  Fair Valued")
ax0.fill_between(data.index,data.Y3, data.Y4, alpha=.3, facecolor='sandybrown',label="90% <- 115% --  Modestly Overvalued")
ax0.fill_between(data.index,data.Y4, data.Y5, alpha=.3, facecolor='r',label="        >  115% --  Significantly Overvalued")
legend=ax0.legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, framealpha=1)
legend.get_frame().set_alpha(1)
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('white')
data['USREC'].plot(kind='area', secondary_y=True, ax=ax1, alpha=.25, color='grey',label='Recession')
plt.ylim(ymin=0.0, ymax=0.8)
plt.xlim(['1970-01','2017-12'])
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think one can do anything about the frustration. If you feel that coding a plot is not what you want, you may use graphical plotting software instead. There is however no GUI interface to matplotlib plots. On the other hand, the fact that plots are created with python language makes matplotlib a very versatile tool. In principle it will allow to do much more customized plots than many GUI plotters.

Answer (score 0):

To recreate the problem using a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(2)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1 = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100,4), axis=0)
y2 = np.sort(np.random.rand(10))*100
fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = ax0.twinx()

ax0.plot(y1)
ax0.legend("ABC DEF GHI JKL".split(), framealpha=1, loc=3)

for i in range(5):
    ax1.axvspan(y2[2*i],y2[2*i+1] , alpha=0.25, color="grey", label=str(i))
ax1.legend(framealpha=1, loc=4)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Here the legend is partially hidden behind the semitransparent grey spans.
The reason is that the `ax1` axes is further on top than the `ax0` axes hosting the legend.

A possible solution is to remove the legend from the `ax0` axes and add it to the `ax1` axes, like this:

```
leg.remove()
ax1.add_artist(leg)
```

[image]